# HTML and heights: how do I make a widget as high as _all_ of its descendants?

Tags: html, css

See this simple HTML page:

```
<head>
<style>

.page {

  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  height: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inner {
  height: 11em;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 90%;
}

.inner-again {
  height: 15em;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 95%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body class="page">

  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>And again</p>
      <div class="inner-again">
        <p>AND NOW!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Basically, it's a box of height "auto" which contains an `inner` of height `11em`.
The div `inner` has some text, and then another div -- which is of height `15em`.

I expected the box to cover the whole area, since its height is set to `auto` and it contains two elements. However, it only cover its direct descendant, `inner`.

I obviously don't really understand how heights work in HTML... so I wonder: what am I *actually* missing here?

Plus: how do I actually make a containing div that is *guaranteed* to contain, height-wise, all of its children, grandchildren, grandgrandgranrgrandchildre, etc.? (that is, how do I change `box` so that it's as high as the grey box?)

EDIT: Sorry, this is a dumbed-down version of something much more complex. In real life, `inner` is a Dojo widget, for which there *needs* to be a specified height.

So, a constraint to my question is: **`inner` needs to have a definite height**

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4aeyr/

Comment: Sorry, I added a constraint I didn't put in the original question: `inner` needs to have a height!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `inner` class. If you want to set a minimum height, you should use `min-height` instead of `height`. If you use `height`, the height of element is fixed as 11 em. So that's why the child element overflows, because the height of the child is bigger than the parent's height.

CSS:

```
.inner{
                min-height: 11em;
                background-color: yellow;
                width: 90%;
            }
```

But if you don't want to use a minimum height. You can simply remove the height property in inner `class`.

CSS:

```
.inner {
                background-color: yellow;
                width: 90%;
            }
```

I'm sorry for bad English. I hope my explanation is clear enough and helpful.. :)

EDIT:

Here you are the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/asubanovsky/y3c3r/) that I made for an example

Comment: Sorry, I added a constraint I didn't put in the original question: inner needs to have a height!

Comment: So you better use min-height instead of height.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/4HSjd/1/

Remove the `height: 11em` or set the height to `auto`:

```
.inner {
  //height: 11em;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 90%;
}
```

If you need to have a specific `height` for `inner`, then be sure it is greater than its element inside. Something like: `height: 30em;`

http://jsfiddle.net/4HSjd/2/

```
.inner {
  height: 30em;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I added a constraint I didn't put in the original question: inner needs to have a height!

Comment: @Merc If you need it to have a `height`, then I guess `inner` should be greater than `inner-again` element. Seems does not make sense to me that your container is smaller than its element inside. Like setting the `height` to `height: 30em;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! They were both 100% correct... I accepted the other one as that user has very few points (53 as I speak), and would like to encourage him to answer more questions! Thank you though... upvoted!